# Populate media asset files using something like `collectstatic`

Tags: django, deployment, assets

How can I use Django's `collectstatic` to populate “media” (model-managed) asset files?

I have a Django app that is using the [“media” files support – files managed and associated with Model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/files/) – for assets like product images and icons for specific instances.

These (for some fields) are not uploaded by users; they are developed along with the model, and described in data fixtures that refer to the files by path.

For those media assets, the files need to be populated when the application is deployed; this means collecting the files from various locations and providing them where the “media” storage expects to find them.

The web app already successfully serves these “media” files once they are collected. The [correct configurations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#media-root) are working.

But every time the site is deployed, the media files need to be collected together from the app-model locations that make sense for development, into the central directory tree (`MEDIA_ROOT`) where the files storage expects them to be served from.

This task is very closely implemented by the tool `collectstatic`, for [deploying “static” files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/static-files/deployment/) (files that are intended not to be associated specifically with any model, but with the site as a whole and served outside the context of model permissions).

How can I **make use of `collectstatic` (or its implementation) to collect “media” asset files for deployment**?

Comment: Why would they need to be collected on every deployment? You shouldn't be clearing out your media directory on a deployment

Comment: That's a separate matter, I think @IainShelvington. I've described these as “assets”, please take it as given that these are best deployed by collecting them at deployment time and deploying them fresh.

Comment: You're describing "static" files if they are files that exist in your app(s) and need to be collected when the app is deployed. How do you have entries in a FileField for files that aren't uploaded by a user? A fixture?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/django-media-fixtures/ this package looks like it might do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

(Thanks to @iain-shelvington for this solution. Iain, feel free to make your own answer equivalent to this.)

This job is exactly what the PyPI package ‘[django-media-fixtures](https://pypi.org/project/django-media-fixtures/)’ is for.

> Simple project to copy media files (intended for fixtures loads), pretty much as staticfiles does.
>
> […] Just call manage command `collectmedia`, same as you do with `collectstatic`
> […] And then all files on `media_fixtures` folder in apps will be copied to your MEDIA_ROOT.